# CiPHREX mSIGNA wallet recovery from private key to new wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, buy-bitcoins, msigna

I use mSIGNA for my bitcoin transactions. This is a multi-sig P2SH wallet that requires private keys and an account file to create/view/receive transactions.

I've searched through the documentation and attempted to find answers online but there appears to be a lack of posts regarding mSIGNA.

Is it possible to recover my wallet from private key seed without having access to the 'account' file that mSIGNA requires you to create?